# Entity Framework property required error for properties set in insert procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using the Entity Framework (5.0.0) for a web site, and have an object that I am trying to insert via stored procedure. The object has some properties that do not need to be set upon insertion, as they are set by the stored procedure. The columns for these properties are set as NOT NULL in the database. Entity Framework is complaining that one of these properties is required, which I believe has to do with them not being set upon insertion.

Is there something I am missing, or not fully understanding? Or maybe my design is flawed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find exactly what I was looking for. I scoured for what seemed like an eternity trying to find this, and I'm not sure how I missed it, but anyway, it goes as follows:

When viewing the Properties of a given column in the EDMX, there's a property called "StoreGeneratedPattern". Essentially, this is an enumeration declaring different behaviors of the specified column during insert and update procedures. The options are None, Computed, and Identity.

I initially didn't think this was what I wanted, since these columns are not identity columns, nor are they computed columns. However, that is not what the options are referring to, they just happen to share the same name. In my situation, Identity allows me to specify a value that is generated on insert and remains unchanged on update (per the documentation).

You can find out more about these options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EF code first you probably have a `[Required]` attribute on that property. Just remove it and you should be fine.

If you're using EF model first then the property was inferred to be required because it is NOT NULL in the database. Change the Nullable setting for that column in the EDMX (essentially lying to EF) and EF should stop complaining.

Comment: I assumed changes to the Nullable property would be overwritten when updating the model from the database, but that doesn't seem to be the case, so in essence, this works. However, I was hoping for a less "hacky" way of implementing the desired behavior.